# Motivation for spawning a new process v thread

Tags: c, multithreading, process

I understand that if your program has large segments that can be executed in parallel it would be beneficial to spawn new threads when the instances are not bound by a single resource.  Example of this would be a web server issuing page requests.

Threads are beneficial from the aspect that inter-thread communication is much less costly and context switching is much faster.

Processes give you more security from the aspect that one process cannot "mess" with another processes' contents, whereas if one thread crashes it is likely all threads will crash within said process.

My question is, what are some examples as to when you would want to use a process (for example by fork() in C)?

I can think of if you have a program that wants to launch another program it would make sense to encapsulate that in a new process, but I feel that I am missing some larger reason for starting a new process.

Specifically, when does it make sense to have one program spawn a new process vs thread?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Main reason for using processes is so that the process can crash or go crazy, and the OS will limit the effect that this has on other processes. So for example Firefox has recently started running plugins in separate processes, IIRC Chrome runs different pages in different processes, and web servers for a long time have handled individual requests in separate processes.

There are a few different ways in which OSes apply limits:

- Crashes - as you note, if a thread crashes it generally takes down the whole process. This motivates the browser process boundaries: browsers and browser plugins are complex bits of code subject to constant attack, so it makes sense to take unusual precautions.
- Resource limits. If a thread in your process opens a lot of files, allocates a lot of memory, etc, then it affects you. Another process needn't, because it can be limited separately. So each request in a web server might be more limited in its resource usage than the server as a whole, because you want your server to serve multiple requests simultaneously without any one remote user hogging resources.
- Capabilities. Varies by OS, but just for example you can run a process in a chroot jail to ensure that it doesn't modify or read files it shouldn't, no matter how vulnerable your code is to exploits. For another example, SymbianOS has an explicit list of permissions to do various things with the system ("read user phonebook", "write user phonebook", "decrypt DRM files" and so on). There's no way to surrender permissions that your process has, so if you want to do something highly sensitive, and then fall back to a low-sensitivity mode, you need a process boundary somewhere. One reason to want to do this is security - unknown code or code that might contain security flaws can be somewhat sandboxed, and a smaller quantity of code that isn't limited can be subjected to increased scrutiny. Another reason is simply to have the OS enforce certain aspects of your design.
- Drivers. In general, a device driver controls shared access to a unique system resource. As with capabilities, restricting this access to a single driver process means you can forbid it to all the other processes. For example IIRC TrueCrypt on Windows installs a driver that has enhanced permissions that allow it to register an encrypted container with a drive letter and then act like any other Windows filesystem. The GUI part of the app runs in regular user mode. I'm not sure whether filesystem drivers on Windows actually need an associated process, but device drivers in general might do, so even if this isn't a good example hopefully it gives the idea.

Another potential reason for using processes is that it makes it easier to reason about your code. In multi-threaded code you rely on invariants of all your classes to deduce that access to a particular object is serialized: if your code isn't multi-threaded then you *know* that it is[*]. It's possible to do this with multi-threaded code as well, of course, just make sure you know what thread "owns" each object, and never access an object from a thread that isn't its owner. Process boundaries enforce this rather than just designing for it. Again, not certain that this is the motivation, but for example the World Community Grid client can use multiple cores. In that mode it runs multiple processes with a completely different task in each, so it has the performance benefits of the additional cores, without any individual task needing to be parallelizable, or the code for any task needing to be thread-safe.

[*] well, as long as it wasn't created in shared memory. You also need to avoid unexpected recursive calls and the like, but that's usually a simpler problem than synchronizing multi-threaded code.

Answer (score 0):

Threads share the same memory with other thread in same process. So in case you want to pass data from one thread to another you have to take care of locking, syncing etc which is complex and buggy thing and should be avoided. If one of the thread crash it will bring down the whole process. Thread creating is light as opposed to creating a new process.

In separate process for each task the pros is that you don't need to worry about shared mutable data which needs to be locked and synced as you will be using message passing to communicate with the process and even if a process crash it wont take down your whole application (browsers does that toady : each tab = new process). The cons is that process creation is more heavy then thread creation. Remember that these individual process may have more than one thread.

So using the above mentioned points you can choose the best approach for your specific application. There is no silver bullet and it all "depends" on case to case.

One important point to remember is that in both cases you should use "pools" (thread pool and process pool) and not create new thread/process for each task that you want to perform. 
The browser example : each tab has own process doesn't use pool as the process in this case are not "worker process" which are supposed to be waiting for the main process to give them some task and then after completing it again go into wait state.

Comment: It seems someone was looking for a "silver bullet" answer

Comment: Instead of "buggy" I think you meant "human-error-prone". There is nothing buggy about synchronization on a correct system. Also I think your advice about pools is too broad. For some cases they may make sense, but on modern systems thread creation is sufficiently cheap that the complexity (and potentially-imposed limits on simultaneously processed requests) inherent in pools may severely outweigh their marginal usefulness for performance.

Comment: Thread creation is definitely cheap but the problem is : If you create too many threads, the penalty of context switch will hamper the performance of your application. In todays world of multi-core it is better to have a thread pool which has thread count = as many cores you have. Threading is a very low level concept (for parallelization) in todays environment and you need better abstractions for parallelization and concurrent programming (like those in Erlang, F# etc)

Comment: I think that assumption is outdated and mistaken. Otherwise M:N threading would not have been abandoned.

Comment: @R - From your comments it seems that you are a C/C++ guy :) . Is that assumption correct ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that threads have a limited stack, which gives you a limit to the amount of work you can proceed with them. Bot OTH you can exchange data very simply, using shared memory and thread messages. Having 10 threads, each performing a simple task, is quite easy to manage, even on a *baseline* computer.

Using processes is, in my opinion, harder to manage because you have to handle the data transfer between the parent and the child. You have to use pipes, message queues, etc... and the memory transfers are way more costly than in threads. Stopping a process involves sending a `SIG_KILL`. OTH you get the crash-security: a process crashing won't take your main application.

**thread examples**
- I/O read/writes handling: you pass a buffer, the thread notifies you when the write/read is complete
- matrix multiplication: you can split the matrix computing by lines or columns, and the task is pretty simple

**process examples**
- exporting some data to an image format, using some complex compression
- an indexer process, which gathers metadata and formats them into the internal format of your app
- each new drawing window of a complex app

**tl;dr**
IMHO:
- Use *processes* if the task is complex.
- Use *threads* if the taks is light.

Comment: I disagree with your conclusion. Complex and light tasks are equally doable in threads, and unlike creating a new process, creating threads can be done completely transparently in library code without the calling application even being able to detect (without poking around in `/proc`, etc.) that a thread was created. Processes do have a purpose, but it's mainly when you want to isolate privilege levels or run an external binary (possibly because it uses ugly/broken libraries that would conflict with your main application's symbol namespace).